# How can I get rid of these arrows in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I mistakenly placed some key on the keyboard and as a result of which these arrows have started to appear whenever I select some text. How can I get rid of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those look like tab characters. Maybe *View* -> *Render Whitespace* is checked?